# Handling multiple offers from different peers in WebRTC using Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, webrtc

I am trying to make a video conferencing application where all peers connect in a mesh, what i am doing is when a peer joins the room, they broadcast their id to everyone present in the room, and everyone calls back to the broadcaster with the id. Sometimes its able to connect to everyone but other times, the broadcaster received all the offers but send back only some answers, skipping the other offers. Is there a way to use async/await to handle and send answers back one by one? I am very new to javascript and WebRTC, i tried many things but can't figure it out.

Code to handle the offers:

```
socket.on('message',function(message) {
 if(message.type === 'offer') {
   if(message.specific === clientId){
      if(message.isSuperNode === false)
        isNodeCap++;
      createPeerConnection(message.userid,message.isSuperNode);
      pc.peerConnection.addStream(pc.mixer.getMixedStream());
      pc.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
      console.log("Offer Received");
      localPeerList.push(pc);
      doAnswer(message.userid);
    }
});

function createPeerConnection(userid,isSN) {
  try {
    var obj ={};
    obj.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig);
    obj.mixer = new MultiStreamsMixer([localStream]);
    obj.mixer.startDrawingFrames();
    obj.connectionWith = userid;  
    obj.isSuperNode = isSN;
    obj.peerConnection.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate
    obj.peerConnection.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    obj.peerConnection.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    pc = Object.assign({},obj);
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
    return;
  }
}

function doAnswer(userid) {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  pc.peerConnection.createAnswer().then(function(offer){
    pc.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer).then(function(){
        answering = true;
      }
    ).catch(function(e) {
      alert(e.name);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the semantics in your example but a potential issue is that `doAnswer` isn't "awaited".

So you could try make the message handler async and await the `doAnswer` call like so:

```js
socket.on('message', async function(message) {
 if(message.type === 'offer') {
   if(message.specific === clientId){
      if(message.isSuperNode === false)
        isNodeCap++;
      createPeerConnection(message.userid,message.isSuperNode);
      pc.peerConnection.addStream(pc.mixer.getMixedStream());
      pc.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
      console.log("Offer Received");
      localPeerList.push(pc);
      await doAnswer(message.userid);
    }
});

async function doAnswer(userid) {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  const offer = await pc.peerConnection.createAnswer();
  try {
    await pc.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    answering = true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(e.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to javascript and webrtc, then [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) would simplify the webrtc handling. It's basically a wrapper for the RTCPeerconnection.

Here is an [simple project](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer) with a [DEMO](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/) for a multi-user video call with simple-peer.